# How to add permissions to roles

Tags: discord.py

I have looked on the internet a lot, and I haven't seemed to find anything based around permissions for roles on a discord bot in Python. I believe I have seen it done on js, but nothing else. I am wondering whether I am able to add permissions to certains roles using their names. Any input would help greatly! I would also like to know how to move roles up and down the list.

Answer (score 1):

Use this if you are using rewrite: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Permissions

Use this if you are using async: 
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Permissions